# Can you add a check list to a PR screen or the approval screen for a pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

So we wish to add a check list to the PR screen or the approval part so that the approvers can see that the correct documentation has been created.
Here is picture of the kind of thing we want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkjNH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible! Have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-templates?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

As **`@user2704177`** mentioned, you can follow the documentation "[**Pull request templates**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-templates?view=azure-devops)" to add a default pull request template with the content like as below in the default branch of your repository.

```
### Before approving this PR, please also review:
- [ ] TST Created?
- [ ] Elevation Plan Completed?
- [ ] Costing Approved?
```

[image]

After adding the default pull request template, whenever a new pull request is created in the repository, the content of template will be automatically applied for the description of the new pull request.

[image]

Then on the page of the pull request, you can click on the checkbox before each item to check/uncheck them in the description.

[image]